# Hide Empty <div>'s When Table Rows Are Less Than 3

Tags: jsp

I'm having a blank moment and I can't for the life of me remember how to do it.

Basically I have a `<table>` and below this I have an empty `<div>` displayed but I don't the `<div>` to be displayed if the table rows are less than 3.

I know the answer will be easy but I can't for the life of me remember how to do it.

I want it in an `if` statement.

This is a copy of my code which generates each row in my table:

```
    foreach (var row in table.Rows)
    { %>
        <tr>
            <%
              foreach (var cell in row.Cells)
              { %>
                  <td><%=cell.Content%></td>
           <% } %>
        </tr>
  <% } %>
```

Its a Monday morning and I haven't quite woke up yet, but your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not HTML! You should tag it correctly.

Comment: @murday1983 : Basically add a condition like `if ( table.Rows.length > 3 ) { show div part  } ` Getting the row length will do the trick for u. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Roy.  Thanks.  New it was something so simple.  I was missing the word 'Count'.